# Why the ExecuteResult is not being called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application. There is a class(adminAccess) with a method RestrictAccess to check if the user exists in the database and if not to return new HttpForbiddenResult() with an access denied page.

Then i am calling this class from my controller like this:

```
adminAccess access = new adminAccess();
```

Although the class is being initialised fine , after some debugging i found out that the ExecuteResult is not being called in my HttpForbiddenResult class and no ViewResult is being created to show to the user the Access Denied page.

If i just copy the contents of my adminAccess class directly in the ActionResult of my controller, everything works fine but i dont want to have this ammount of code at every page.

Can you please help me find out where is the problem ?

```
public class adminAccess 
    {
        string strLoginName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        private BookingSystemEntities SystemDB = new BookingSystemEntities();

        public object RestrictAccess()
        {
            try
            {
                var accessList = SystemDB.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users where UserLogin = '" + strLoginName + "' and (UserRoleId = 1 or UserRoleId = 2) ").ToList();

                foreach (var item in accessList)
                {

                    item.UserLogin.ToString();

                    if ((item.UserLogin != strLoginName) || (item.UserLogin == null) || (item.UserLogin == string.Empty))
                    {

                        return new HttpForbiddenResult();
                    }
                }

                if (accessList.Count == 0)
                {
                 //     return HttpNotFound();
                    return new HttpForbiddenResult();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Please contact the Helpdesk with the following message :", ex);
            }

           return RestrictAccess();
        }

    }


 public class HttpForbiddenResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
    {

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)   
        {     
            base.ExecuteResult(context);         
            // creates the ViewResult adding ViewData and TempData parameters       
            ViewResult result = new ViewResult      
            {            
                ViewName = "AccessDenied",          
                ViewData = context.Controller.ViewData,        
                TempData = context.Controller.TempData   

            };         
            result.ExecuteResult(context);   
        }

        // calls the base constructor with 403 status code   
        public HttpForbiddenResult()        
            : base(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden")    
        {   
        }


    }
```

Comment: When you step through this in the debugger, where does it go wrong?  Also, why is `RestrictAccess()` recursively calling itself?  I don't see any terminating condition, so I suspect this would result in a `StackOverflowException` being thrown.

Comment: And when called from your controller, if you want your result to be executed you need to call it with the `return` keyword as in `return access.RestrictAccess();`

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to delete "RestrictAccess()" - i was just trying to call directly the method...

Comment: When i step through the debugger it doesnt access this part of the code at all : "public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)" while if i take my adminAccess class and copy its contents directly to the actionresult of the controller everything works fine